# Change default website language

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I've been working on a Social Network website in PHP and MySQL lately and when I'm trying to test it, my browser (Chrome) asks me if I would like to translate the page content from Italy (not sure why Italy) to any language.

Is there any way I can set a default language for the website, so that this won't occur?

I've tried both the following codes already, but it does not change anything.

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en_US" />
 <html lang="en">
```

Thanks in regards,

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">` or `<html lang="en">` - [Read More](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#meta)

Comment: @Darren Thanks for the comment, but it did not help.

Comment: mi piace il vostro questione. By the looks of the answer given, I for one didn't know this. Molto bene!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can disable it easy by adding the folllow metatag

```
<meta name="google" value="notranslate">
```

Good luck amigo

Comment: It anoying I know keep the content language to en_US just for search engines and add the google notranslate metatag and it will work and maintain good SEO results

Comment: Mark the question as correct so people asking for help and comming to this question get the right answer too like you